# Putting orderby from highest to lowest in database query

Tags: php, laravel-5

1.I've a confusion on how to add sort orderby(highest to lowest) in my database query for the age.I've tried some few codes but it generates an error.Any help here is much appreciated.

```
public function ListOrgaScholar($ship_id){
        $ship = Scholarship::find($ship_id);
        $ship_age_from = $ship->ship_age_from;
        $ship_age_to = $ship->ship_age_to;
        $scholars = (new Scholar)->newQuery()->select('*');
        $scholars->whereBetween(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,scholars.scholar_birthday,CURDATE())'),array($ship_age_from,$ship_age_to)); 
        $scholars = $scholars->get();

}
```

2.Same us here.How to add orderby(highest to lowest) since it is two different where clause.The `$ship_gpa_from` and `$ship_gpa_to` are inputs of grade.

```
    public function ListOrgaScholar($ship_id){
           $ship = Scholarship::find($ship_id);
           $ship_gpa_from = $ship->ship_gpa_from;
           $ship_gpa_to = $ship->ship_gpa_to;
           $scholars = (new Scholar)->newQuery()->select('*');

          if($ship_gpa_from)
            $scholars->where('scholar_GPA', '>=', $ship_gpa_from);
          if($ship_gpa_to)
            $scholars->where('scholar_GPA', '<=', $ship_gpa_to);

    $scholars = $scholars->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried returning the results as collection and then applying collection functions on them? The code would look somewhat like this:

```
$scholarship = Scholarship::find($id);

$scholars = Scholar::all();

$selectedScholars  = $scholars->filter(function ($item, $key) {
    $scholarAge = Carbon::now() - $item->scholar_birthday //this depends on the value of scholar_birthday;
    return ($scholarAge >= $scholarship->ship_age_from &&  $scholarAge <= $scholarship->ship_age_from);
})->sortBy("scholar_birthday");
```